How do I find all natural numbers pairs $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{a^3 - b}{a^3 + b} = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{b^2 + a^2}$, with $a \le 10^5$ and $b < 10^5$?
The title isn't long enough, there are also conditions where $a \le 10^5$ and $b < 10^5$.
I've tried to pair $a^3 - b = b^2 - a^2$ and also $a^3 + b = b^2 + a^2$.
And I ended up getting $a = b = 1$.
However, I’m guessing there exists another solution to this problem.
Any help or hints would be appreciated! Thanks.

Note that the equation can be simplified to $a^5 = b^3$.

First, cross-multiply to get:
$$(a^3 - b)(b^2 + a^2) = (b^2 - a^2)(a^3 + b)$$
$$a^3b^2 + a^5 - b^3 - a^2b = a^3b^2 + b^3 - a^5 - a^2b$$
$$2a^5 - 2b^3 = 0$$
$$a^5 = b^3$$
So, the value must be both a perfect third power and a perfect fifth power, and therefore a perfect 15th power.
$$\exists k\in\mathbb{N} :a^5 = b^3 = k^{15}$$
$$a = k^3 \text{ and } b = k^5$$
Brute-forcing the $k$ values that fit the given domain constraints gives:
$$(a, b) \in \{(1, 1), (8, 32), (27, 243), (64, 1024), (125, 3125), (216, 7776), (343, 16807), (512, 32768), (729, 59049) \}$$

Cross multiply to get $a^5-b^3+a^3b^2-a^2b=-a^5+b^3-a^2b+a^3b^2$, which becomes $a^5=b^3$.
The solutions are therefore of the form $a=k^3$ and $b=k^5$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
